# Regex expression for numbers and leading zeros just with a dot and decimal

Tags: regex, format

I'm trying to find a regex for numeric inputs. We can receive a leading 0 just if we add a dot for adding 1 or 2 decimal numbers. And of course just accept numbers.

These are the scenarios that we can accept:

```
0.01 
1.1
1.02
120.01
```

We **can't** accept these values

```
0023
0100
.01
.12
```

Which regex is the best option for these cases?

Until now we try we the following regex for accepting just number and dots

```
[A-Za-z,]
```

And also we try with the following ones:

`^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:[0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]{1})?|(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?|(?:\.[0-9]{3})*(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?)$`

`"/^[-]?[$]\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})*\.\d{2}$/"`

`"/(^(\d{1})\.{0,1}([0-9]){0,2}$)|(^([1-9])\d{0,2}(\,\d{0,3})$)/g"`

`(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?`

And the next one for deleting the leading zeros but it didn't work for 0.10 cases

`^0+`

Comment: [Edit] your question and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Ok @Julia I'm going to do that right away!

Comment: Maybe `^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/ULntkD/1

Comment: You have not explained al cases. What about `0.00`? Do you want to match `55`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew effectively, I didn't explained all the cases. But I'll be checking the minimum value 0.10 so in that case the 0.00 isn't valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a negative lookahead is supported, you can exclude matches that start with a zero and have no decimal part.

```
^(?!0\d*$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!0+\d*$)` Negative lookahead, assert not a zero followed by optional digits at the right
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Match an optional decimal part with 1 or 2 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F4oiSd/1)

Comment: this regex accept 00.4 values, how can I do for accepting just one leading zero. Instead of 00.4 --> 0.4

Comment: @camilablnpa You can do that using for example `^(?!0\d*$)(?!00\d*\.)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/bDCzCw/1 Or perhaps `^(?!0\d*$)\d(?:[1-9]\d*)?(?:\.\d{1,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/FdJnOv/1

Answer (score 1):

I would go with `^(0|[1-9]\d*|(0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d+)$`

You can test here: https://regex101.com/r/oNMgR9/1

#### Explanation

- `^` means : *match the beginning of the string (or line if the `m` flag is enabled)*.
- `$` means : *match the end of the string (or line if the `m` flag is enabled)*.
- `(a|b)` means *match "a" **or** match "b"* so I'll use this to match either "0" alone or any number not starting with a "0". It's the syntax for a logical ***or***.
- `.` alone is used to match any char. So you have to escape it if you want to match the dot character. This is why I wrote `0\.` instead of `0.`.
- `[  ]` is used to list some characters you want to match. It can be a range if you use the `-` char, so `[1-9]` means any digit char from "1" to "9".
- `\d` is to match a digit. It's totally equivalent to `[0-9]`.
- `*` means : *match the preceding pattern 0 or many times*, so `\d*` means that it will match 0 or many times a digit, so it will match "8" or "465" or "09" but also an empty string "". If you want to match the preceding pattern at least once or many times then you use `+` instead of `*`. So `\d+` won't match an empty string "" but `\d*` would match it.

#### A) Just a number not starting with 0

`[1-9]\d*` will match any digit from 1 to 9 and then optionnaly followed by other digits. This will match numbers without a decimal point.

#### B) Just 0

`0` alone is a possibility. This is because the case above isn't covering it.

#### B) A number with decimals

`(0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d+` will match either a "0" alone or a number not starting by "0" and then followed by a point and some other digits (which have to be present because we don't want to match "45." without the numbers behind the dot).

### Better alternative

[The solution from @TheFourthBird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974195/653182) is a bit cleaner with the use of a negative lookahead. It's just a bit different to understand. And he read the question completely: You wanted 1 or 2 digits after the decimal. I forgot about that, so, effectively, `\d+` should be replaced by `\d{1,2}` as you don't want more than 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?![0.]+$)(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ULntkD/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0.]+$)` - fail the match if there are just zeros or dots till end of string
- `(?:[1-9]\d*|0)` - either a non-zero digit followed with any zero or more digits or a zero
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?`  - optionally followed with a sequence of a `.` and one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.